# rosservice call Gazebo get_link_properties fails "... responded with an error: " or crashes gzserver

Tags: gazebo, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04 
Fuerte

Hi 
I'm having problems using:

```
rosservice call gazebo/get_joint_properties ...
rosservice call gazebo/get_link_properties ...
```

Firstly I am launching a Gazebo simulation, with spawns a urdf model in a world. 
I have also found the same errors testing the NASA R2 simulation.

While Gazebo is running, I can successfully execute:

```
rosservice call gazebo/get_world_properties
```

and

```
rosservice call gazebo/get_model_properties '{model_name: MyModel}'
```

However, if I try to get the properties of a known link:

```
rosservice call gazebo/get_link_properties '{link_name: "link1"}'
```

or

```
rosservice call gazebo/get_link_properties '{link_name: "MyModel::link1"}'
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: service [/gazebo/get_link_properties] responded with an error:
```

and if I try to get the properties of a non-existent link:

```
rosservice call gazebo/get_link_properties '{link_name: "blah"}'
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

but worse is that Gazebo crashes with:

```
gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::physics::Link]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[empty_world_server-2] process has died [pid 22661, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /home/username/ros_workspace/my/ros/project/path/empty.world __name:=empty_world_server __log:=/home/username/.ros/log/33194194-d723-11e1-9760-5c260a0c5681/empty_world_server-2.log].
log file: /home/username/.ros/log/33194194-d723-11e1-9760-5c260a0c5681/empty_world_server-2*.log
```

Similarly, trying a service call to gazebo/get_joint_properties also fails.

I recently updated all my ubuntu ros-fuerte packages, but I can't remember if this was working before that.

So, do I have the correct syntax?  and why am I getting this error "ERROR: service [/gazebo/get_link_properties] responded with an error" ? 
Can I trace the error in more detail?

Also if it is normal behaviour, maybe Gazebo shouldn't crash for unknown link/joint names.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39869/rosservice-call-gazebo-get_link_properties-fails-%22...-responded-with-an-error:-%22-or-crashes-gzserver/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-07-26**:
I get the same behavior when I try to use the GetLinkForce() and GetLinkTorque() methods in the Joint Class for plug-ins... maybe related? Does your log file ever print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a problem with the Gazebo ROS API. In the Electric branch, looking up a link was coded (gazeboros.cpp)

```
gazebo::Body* body = dynamic_cast(gazebo::World::Instance()->GetEntityByName(req.link_name));
if (body == NULL)
```

while in the Fuerte and Groovy branches it's (gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp)

```
gazebo::physics::LinkPtr body = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast(this->world->GetEntity(req.link_name));
if (body)
```

The check is thus reversed, which shouldn't be the case. I've submitted a patch:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/5580/

---

Originally posted by [wcaarls](https://answers.ros.org/users/3110/wcaarls/) with karma: 76 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-16**:
Should this be fixed in ROS Groovy? I am still having the same problem with gazebo/get_joint_properties in Groovy.

**Comment by [wcaarls](https://answers.ros.org/users/3110/wcaarls/) on 2013-02-10**:
As far as I can tell, this has not been fixed in Groovy.